# Showing that ODE is not of Sturm-Liouville form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

The PDE
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-V_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

can be separated into two ODEs by the method of separation of variables, and the ODE for $M(x)$ is
$$\frac{d^2M}{dx^2}(x)-\frac{V_0}{D}\frac{dM}{dx}(x)=-\frac{\lambda}{D} M(x)$$

If we now multiply this equation by the integrating factor
$$\exp\left(-\int \frac{V_0}{D}dx\right)$$
we'll get the equation
$$\left[M'(x)\exp\left(-\int \frac{V_0}{D}dx\right)\right]'=-\frac{\lambda}{D}\exp\left(-\int \frac{V_0}{D}dx\right)M(x)$$

Why is this not an equation of the Sturm-Lioville form?

Comment: I don't understand your problem here. It is, according to what you have written.

Comment: I'm asked to show that the ODE for $M(x)$ is not of Sturm-Liouville form.

Comment: It's not in Sturm-Liouville form until you multiply by an integrating factor. I suspect that's how the question should be interpreted.